# Reading file contents in a different maven module

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven project with parent module (P) and multiple child modules (C1, C2, C3..). I want to read a file present in module C1 (src/main/resources/sample.txt) in module C2. I have added C1 as dependency in C2 pom.

I have tried specifying the relative file path as `../C1/src/main/resources/sample.txt` and it works well. Is there a cleaner solution to this?

Comment: Never do such a thing cause it shows your design is flawed. Apart from that reading a file with the above given path will only work during build time but will fail during runtime cause during run time the modules C1 and C2 etc. will be JAR files and you can't access C1 jar from C2 ...so resources should be located where they are needed. and should be read via `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/sample.txt")`...